# Maximum number of items to delete has been reached. Please contact the Site Collection Administrator

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am facing this error when i am programatically delete record from sharepoint list. column is lookup column in another list and i have set cascade delete option enable in list. I am facing below error. Can any one give me solution to delete record programatically

**Maximum number of items to delete has been reached.  Please contact the Site Collection Administrator.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

> Open SharePoint 2010 Management Shell and execute the following:
>
> $site = spsite "URL"
>
> Now we have to set the maximum number of items that can be checked in a Cascade 
>   or Restrict delete operation.
>
> It is applicable to lists which have referential integrity enabled in them.
>
> $site.WebApplication.CascadeDeleteMaximumItemLimit = [number of items]
>
> By default the [number of items] = 1000

Here is a [source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/bbca12c3-674f-4ad1-93a1-0783dc1f20f8) post;

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: please summarize the gist of the solution in the post. Links can go bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the CascadeDeleteMaximumItemLimit property. This controls the duration of a short-term Web site lock that is taken to perform referential integrity delete operations.

You can try this in powershell:

```
$site = spsite "http://[your site collection URL]"
$site.WebApplication.CascadeDeleteMaximumItemLimit = [# of items]
```